# Dart Flutter : How to use multiple statements in ternary inside a flutter widget

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to write such a line, and within this line I want change a variable value?

```
opacity: condition == true ? 1, stringName ='Steve' : 0
```

Comment: Not sure what the semantics of this statement should be. What is `stringName = 'steve'` supposed to do here? Is it that you want to have 2 statements for the `condition == true` case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not sure what you expect the code to do exactly but my guess

```
opacity: condition == true ? (){ stringName = 'Steve'; return 0; }() : 0;
```

You can't have a list of expressions in the true or false part, only one single expression.

Comment: I was thinking it may be possible to do two statements after the condition is true, but only one expression is allowed. Thanks

Comment: do those brackets "()" mean something?

Comment: Yes. `(){}` creates a function and the additional `()` cause it to be called. This way you can have multiple statements.

Comment: I was just looking for a solution to "need statement in expression". Thank you for this nice trick. Assume you have a Text(child:text) widget and want to print the text. This does it: Text(child: () {print(text); return text;}()); Cute.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted

```
opacity : condition== true ? 1 : stringName == "Steve" ? 0 : 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will be able to achieve the best result in a case like this using ternary expressions. Instead, you can create a sperate function that you can bundle in all your conditions and maybe return an appropriate variable as the case may be.

After the you can call the ***SetState() Function*** to update your widget.